# how to make java trust my application

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have an application overriding the default toolkit, by setting the system.property awt.toolkit. For the standalone application I set this up in the code, by using System.setProperty(String, String). This works just fine. But when I try to run via webstart, the property is set to late, because java already set up the toolkit (for splash or webstart console maybe).

So I added the property to the jnlp, but without any effect. The property is not even passed, to the vm. I figured out, that it is considered "unsecure" by java itself and my applications is considered "untrusted".

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources)

> For an untrusted application, system properties set in the JNLP file
>   will only be set by Java Web Start if they are considered secure.

I have a signed application with a valid certificate from a certificate authority, but still my application is considered untrusted. i did all the steps suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157450/how-to-make-a-machine-trust-a-self-signed-java-application), but without any effect. I don't get any of [those dialogs](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/trusted_signed_variations.xml) about untrusted application or publisher information anymore, but I still do not get the property passed to my virtual machine.

any ideas, what I could try next?

BTW: still using java 7 as runtime

Comment: found the following entry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400725/with-java-update-7-45-the-system-properties-no-more-set-from-jnlp-tag-property will try the comment about adding the jnlp to the jar file tomorrow. But as i am using dynamic jnlp (generated by a perl script) this is not really sufficient.

Comment: another entry [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571562/javaws-java-7-update-45-cannot-send-properties?lq=1) confirms that

Comment: adding APPLICATION.JNLP to signed jar file did not work. Also see [java documentation for signed jnlp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/signedJNLP.html)